# Javascript React Single Page Application + Amazon S3: Permalinks issue

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, single-page-application, permalinks, html5-history

I am using an S3 bucket as static web solution to host a single page React application.
The react application works fine when I hit the root domain *s3-bucket.amazon.com* and the HTML5 history api works fine every time I click on a link the new url looks fine: _http://s3-bucket.amazon.com/entities/entity_id_
The problem happens when I use permalinks to access the application. Let's assume I am typing the same url (_http://s3-bucket.amazon.com/entities/entity_id_) in the browser I will get the following error from Amazon S3:

```
404 Not Found
Code: NoSuchKey
Message: The specified key does not exist.
Key: users
RequestId: 3A4B65F49D07B42C
HostId: j2KCK4tvw9DVQzOHaViZPwT7+piVFfVT3lRs2pr2knhdKag7mROEfqPRLUHGeD/TZoFJBI4/maA=
```

Is it possible to make Amazon S3 to work nicely with permalinks and HTML5 history api? Maybe it can act as proxy?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Solution using AWS CloudFront:

Step 1: Go to CloudFront

Click on distribution id

Go to the Error page tab

Click on Create Custom Error Response

Step 2: Fill the form as

HTTP Error Code: 404

TTL: 0

Custom Error Response: Yes

Response Page Path: /index.html

HTTP Response Code: 200

source: https://medium.com/@nikhilkapoor17/deployment-of-spa-without-location-strategy-61a190a11dfc

Answer (score 2):

Sadly S3 does not support the wildcard routing required for single page apps (basically you want everything after the host in the url to serve index.html, but preserve the route.

So `www.blah.com/hello/world` would actually serve `www.blah.com/index.html` but pass the route to the single page app.

The good news is you can do this with a CDN such as Fastly (Varnish) in front of S3. Setting up a rule such as:

```
if(req.url.ext == "" ) {
    set req.url = "/index.html"; 
}
```

This will redirect all non asset requests (anything without a file extension) to index.html on the domain.

Comment: Best answer around. Works perfectly on Fastly

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience running SPA on Amazon S3, but this seems to be a problem of url-rewriting. 
It is one thing do have the history (html5) api rewrite your url when running your application / site. 
But allowing rewritten urls to be accessible when refreshing or cold-surfing to your site definitely needs url-rewriting on a server level.
I'm thinking web.confg (IIS), .htaccess (Apache) or nginx site configuration.

It seems the same question already got asked some time ago: https://serverfault.com/questions/650704/url-rewriting-in-amazon-s3

Comment: I read the article.Basically is rewriting the url as it the browser didn't support HTML5 history api. What i am looking for is more of proxy functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the same name for the index and error files on "Static website hosting" properties. See linked image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86u8R.png).

Answer (score 0):

Old question but simplest way would be to use hash routing. So instead of mydomain.com/somepage/subpage it would be mydomain.com/#/somepage/subpage